# How to set the BoxDecoration background color

Tags: flutter

My code:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(widget.title),
        ),
        body: Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
          width: 268,
          height: 24,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.yellow,
              border: Border.all(width: 2.0, color: Colors.pink),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0)),
        ));
  }
```

Why does “color: Colors.yellow” not work?

the screenshot

https://i.loli.net/2019/05/07/5cd12fb162fce.png

Comment: Just tried on my laptop, it works. Can you run 'flutter doctor' and share the output?

Comment: @PhucTran 
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.2.1, on Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601], locale zh-CN)
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
    ! Some Android licenses not accepted.  To resolve this, run: flutter doctor --android-licenses
[√] Android Studio (version 3.3)
[√] Connected device (1 available)

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.

Comment: It is working fine for me also, Share the themes you have added in your `MaterialApp`

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been solved, but I don't know the specific reason

It is normal on the real machine, only the problem on the simulator